# Como fazer para quando eu clicar botão,abrir link em outra janela

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

exemplo essa imagem abaixo,eu cliquei no botão e abrir em uma pequena janela!
[image: veja a imagem]

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('pagina.html','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">Clique aqui</a><noscript>Você precisa estar com o javascript ativado, caso contrário <a href="pagina.html" target="_blank">clique aqui</a></noscript>
```

Comment: obrigado amigo!!

Comment: mais ta abrindo meu proprio site?

Comment: como faço pra abrir outro?

Comment: no lugar do `pagina.html` você pode especificar um endereço de url

Comment: ok vlw!! Mt obrigado

Comment: O local onde especifica o endereço desejado é no atributo `href`, do elemento `<a>`...

Comment: @MagicHat, a nova janela é aberta usando javascript. Por isso possuí o `#` dentro do `href`. Nesse caso, precisa especificar dentro do onclick mesmo. Dessa forma, você pode testar no navegador da seguinte maneira: `window.open('http://www.google.com.br','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370');`

Comment: amigo,agora aqui outra dúvida,como faço apra quando eu fechar aquela tela,a pagina atualizar sozinha?

Comment: @RonnyAmarante as duas formas, estão corretas, dependendo da organização do projeto, uma será a melhor opção.

Comment: @MagicHat, fiz um teste aqui para te mostrar. Dê uma olhada, pls: http://jsbin.com/lonipasoco/edit?html,output

Comment: @RonnyAmarante o que exatamente você desejou mostrar ?

Comment: @MagicHat; qual prevalece. Principalmente porque você nunca irá aplicar isso inline. Caso o seu js não tenha sido carregado, ele apenas encaminhará para o href sem abrir em uma nova janela.

Comment: @RonnyAmarante veja a edição que fiz na minha resposta, na parte do javascript, onde uso `this.href` e entenderá o meu ponto de vista.

Comment: @MagicHat; Caso o js não esteja habilitado você não precisa do fallback `noscript`, no seu caso ele irá abrir em uma nova aba o conteúdo. Caso o JS ainda não tenha sido carregado, ele irá abrir em uma nova aba, não seguindo a proposta da questão. No seu código eu não vejo necessidade do `noscript` e você?

Comment: @RonnyAmarante Não, não há a necessidade, fica até melhor. Tá explicado, o porque  do `href` ser um caminho melhor, no meu ponto de vista... Método "socrático" sempre funciona, para ambos os envolvidos... Vlw, man ;)

Answer (score 0):

Veja este exemplo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" target="_blank">Visit our HTML tutorial!</a>

<p>Se você colocar o valor do atributo "target" como "_blank", o link abrirá uma nova janela</p>

</body>
</html>
```

E para especificar o tamanho use Javascript

```
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157601/como-fazer-para-quando-eu-clicar-bot%C3%A3o-abrir-link-em-outra-janela" onClick="window.open(this.href,'pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">Nova Página</a>
```

[Fonte SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444356/html-open-link-in-new-fixed-size-window)